# Need preview pane for meeting agenda replies

Tags: 2010

I have a customer who was migrated to sharepoint 2010 from previous version. When adding an agenda we need to be able to view the replies to the agenda within the site where the agenda's and replies are posted. We do not want to have to open each reply to review it's contents on an individual basis. Example is the way Outlook works. You can see the email without opening it. Can this be done in Sharepoint 2010. Customer claims it was an option before the migration.